# Calculate index of array using character pointer

Tags: c

Please tell me meaning of statment

```
printf("%s",single[*num-'1']);
```

In this statment what index number is produced by [*num-'1']??..i dont want number but want   explanation.

Comment: Explanation - Somebody is writing code that is not maintainable/readable. Did they have a problem with job security?

Answer (score 3):

`num` is dereferenced, and `'1'`, or 0x31, is subtracted from the resultant value.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void convert(char *num);
int main()
{
 char num[15];
 printf("Enter the number");
 gets(num);
 convert(num);
}
void convert(char *num)
{
 int len;
 char *single[]={"","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};
 
 
 len=strlen(num);
 if(len==1)
 {
  printf("%s",single[*num-'1']);
 }
}

Comment: Now tel me in detail..

Comment: It still does *exactly* what I said.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("%s",single[*num-'1']);
```

in this statement you are calculating index  of two dimensional array index single[index]. and printing it

**if *num equals to '3' and its ascii value is 51

'1' ascii value is 49**

single[51-49] equals to single[2]

and now you are printing string single[2].

Answer (score 0):

In C, any character or char is basically an integer type represented by the ASCII characters, so when you say 
`char x = 'a';` 
what gets stored is an integer, that is the ASCII value of a that is `97`.

In other words if you also do `printf("%c",(char)97);` You get the output as the character `'a'`.

So when you do `*num` - what you get is the value stored at the **pointer** `num`.
The next part is subtracting `1` from it...in other words, `1` is a character here which gets converted to an integer, which has a value of `49` in the ASCII table. You can [get the ASCII table reference here](http://www.ascii-code.net/).

So basically you are writing `single[(some value) - 49]`.

Let us suppose `*num=60`
Thus we have `printf("%s",single[60-49]);` equivalent to `printf("%s",single[11]);`

The rest depends on how you use the variable `single`.

I hope this helps.